# Convert "value" "value" to object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Imagine some data like:

```
[
{"name": "ford", "size": 220},
{"name": "chevy", "size": 230},
{"name": "jeep", "size": 240}
]
```

For example, you've done something like `select name, size from sometable`.

Assume the names are unique.

How do you convert it to one *object*, like this:

```
{
ford: 220,
chevy: 230,
jeep: 240,
}
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(arr.map(x => Object.values(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like so:

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "ford", "size": 220 },
  { "name": "chevy", "size": 230 },
  { "name": "jeep", "size": 240 },
];

const sizeByName = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = cur.size;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(sizeByName);
```

Or [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "ford", "size": 220 },
  { "name": "chevy", "size": 230 },
  { "name": "jeep", "size": 240 },
];

const sizeByName = Object.fromEntries(data.map(entry => [entry.name, entry.size]))

console.log(sizeByName);
```

Or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const data = [
  { "name": "ford", "size": 220 },
  { "name": "chevy", "size": 230 },
  { "name": "jeep", "size": 240 },
];

const sizeByName = new Map(data.map(entry => [entry.name, entry.size]));

console.log(Object.fromEntries(sizeByName.entries()));
```

While the `Array.prototype.reduce()` option might be the most common one, as it has existed for many years, I find the more recent `Object.entries()` alternative quite intuitive.